Are there any special actions that I should execute as a reviewer of a sloppy manuscript?
Occasionally, I review a paper that is submitted to a high-quality journal that is one of the journals regarded as the most prestigious journals in my field, and the manuscript is sloppy. The following can be encountered in the manuscript:

Lots of typos.
Sloppy mathematical notation.
Imprecise statements.
Figures with missing legends, labels, imprecise captions.
Incorrect recollection of an aspect of someone else’s past work that’s being cited. Say, a formula from a different paper is being recalled and the meaning of terms is described incorrectly with respect to how they have been described in the original paper.
Sloppy reference list with missing years, authors, or authors referred to in the text by Name et al. instead of Surname et al.

I’m aware that this sloppiness can stem from the researcher who wrote the paper being a junior researcher, e.g., a Ph.D. student. I’m happy to take on a role of being a helpful reviewer who will let the student improve the work and learn from the review. But at the back of my head, I always have the following worry: if the senior researchers on the author’s list haven’t corrected Ph.D. student’s manuscript before submission, then have they actually read the paper carefully and, more importantly, have they checked the Ph.D. student’s research rigorously while it was being conducted? There are always details of the research that has been done that I have no way of checking as a reviewer, especially if the authors don’t provide access to the code they developed. So all I have left is trust that the senior researchers have checked everything.
As a reviewer, should I take the sloppiness in a manuscript as a warning for potential sloppiness in the research? Thus far, I’ve been meticulously listing all typos, all notation inconsistencies, and any imprecisions in my reviewer reports. Is this enough? Is there any other action that is required of me as a reviewer? For example:

Would it be fair to reject a paper on the ground of a sloppy manuscript?
Would it be fair to recommend that the authors go to a lower-tier journal? — this is not ideal anyway, since, in the end, I would like all published research to be rigorously checked, regardless of the tier of the journal.
Would it be fair to mention my worry in the special note to the Editor?

I’m most concerned about cases where one of the senior researchers on the authors list is, say, a well-known mathematician in the field. Is it fair to assume that if that mathematician has read the manuscript, they would have corrected the sloppy mathematical notation and imprecise mathematical statements? And therefore, is it justifiable for me to become worried about the quality of the whole research when “math sloppiness” occurs in a paper where the senior researcher in the authors’ list is a mathematician? In the end, all authors have agreed on the final version of the manuscript and yet I know that that mathematician in the past has written some very good and rigorous papers, so I know that “they can do better”.

Good question, though it may be closed as "opinion-based". I personally will admit that a sloppily written paper does reduce my trust in the parts of the research that I cannot verify, such as computer code and any statistical analysis.

@StephanKolassa, I see, thanks for sharing your view!

Just decline to review such papers. It is the the responsibility of the authors and editors to only send papers for review when they are reasonably well-written.

@SylvainRibault, this is not possible with certain journals which only give me access to the manuscript after I accept the review invitation.

@user166265 : You could look for the submitted article on arXiv before accepting to review: if it is not there, do not review it. Or you could refuse to review for such journals. Or immediately ask for a major stylistic revision before working on the paper's substance.

Decline to review when possible, but not without offering feedback to the author when you do. If the author cares enough, they will invest in polishing their work. Or if you're already committed, reach out to the author informing them that you've taken on the task of reviewing their manuscript and you'd like for them to provide a copy without typos and the other problems mentioned. Communicate that if left as-is, those issues will negatively impact the review.

Papers are not just the content, they are also the presentation. Even in cases where the content is ground breaking, if the presentation means it cannot be understood reliably that is a major problem—both for verifying and building on the results.
I would definitely draw a line at errors that affect how the content is understood. That means simple, isolated tyops in prose are okay but everything that leads to ambiguity is not. Critically, all of these would be problems:


Sloppy mathematical notation.
Imprecise statements.
Figures with missing legends, labels, imprecise captions.
Incorrect recollection of an aspect of someone else’s past work that’s being cited. Say, a formula from a different paper is being recalled and the meaning of terms is described incorrectly with respect to how they have been described in the original paper.


All of these mean that parts of the content must be guessed. Lowering your acceptance and possibly rejecting a paper based on these is perfectly fine. As with any out-of-the-ordinary things, if you know they are unusual for the authors then mentioning this to the editor in addition to adjusting your score can be useful information.

This answer feels wrong to me. If the core ideas of a paper are sound and advance the state of the art, then the writing can be improved to be acceptable. Yes, comment on the issues, and suggest major revisions. Few papers are ever published as first submitted.

@Buffy I don’t see how one can even say that "the core ideas of a paper are sound and advance the state of the art" if the presentation (that means notation and information, not being flashy) are severely lacking. Whether this means one requests revisions or rejection depends on the specific review system, but being difficult or even impossible to understand to scientific standards is definitely a major problem in my book. Papers exist not just to be published but to be read which requires being understandable.

The rest of this discussion has been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

“simple, isolated tyops” ... I see what you did there. ;-)

As with all these questions on reviewing, the key point is to emphasise that you are the reviewer, not the gatekeeper. If a paper has poor lanuage, sloppy notation, incorrect recall of referencs, it is your job to say this (adding examples). You might even note in your review that the sloppiness reflects badly on confidence in the rest of the paper (phrased constructively and with emphathy). But it not your job to decide if that disqualifies the paper or not. That is the job of the editor. If you are worried about the parts of the manuscript you cannot check, then you should note the parts you cannot check in your review. You might even say in the confidential remarks to the editor "I wasn't able to check these parts of the manuscript, but I am worried about them because of the sloppiness in the language, notation etc".
One more thing. You say that you have meticulusly catelogued all the typos. Just as you are not a gatekeeper, you are also not a copy editor. it is good to provide examples, but it is not your job to point out and correct every typographical error.

I have to say although I know I am not a copy editor, I also like to point out the typos during review as I stumble upon them, as it is not a lot of work (you can easily mark them in a PDF).

@Sursula I actually like to take the opposite approach -- I will rarely list every single one in the review. I prefer to say that the language was generally poor and contained many typos, provide a handful of examples, clearly state that the examples are non-exhaustive, but that I would expect to see all of them corrected in any future versions. It's a bit of a test -- if the revised manuscript only corrects the listed examples, it adds to my (negative) opinion of the work, while correcting the majority of typos usually makes me more eager to help further improve the manuscript too.

@Sursula I agree with penelope to not list more than some representative or non-technical typos. The reason is it tends to obscure the review of the actual content, which is the reviewer's main job. That's more important than something the journal's paid copy editors are responsible for anyway.

-1: "But it not your job to decide if that disqualifies the paper or not". Every time I've refereed a paper, I'm literally asked for an accept/reject recommendation. It does sound like it is indeed my job to decide if something disqualifies the paper, from my point of view; then the editor will decide based on that an whatever other information they have.

@MartinArgerami, this answer is suggesting to reject. This seems wrong approach. If the content is well understood and at the standard of the journal then giving "major revision" is also possible option. The revised version will give a chance to decide if the authors are really caring about the manuscript

@Learner: I strongly disagree. We are talking here, as OP describes, about papers that are very poorly written. When you send a very poorly written manuscript to a main journal, you are also sending a strong message that you don't care and that you didn't do your job properly. Why would the journal/referee spend time doing what should have been the researcher's job anyway? At the very very least, a poorly written paper takes unnecessary time out of the referee, and that's unfair.

@martinargerami Most journals I review for don't ask for a reject/accept. Many journals ask for some like 1-5 on categories like novelty, rigour presentation etc, buy not accept/reject. In fact, I tend to refuse to review for those that do, and even if I do, I more often not find my recommendation is not followed.

@martinargerami you assume the authors know that their manuscript is poorly written,  but you have absolutely no way of knowing that.

@IanSudbery: of course. It doesn't change the fact that a very poorly written manuscript should cause an immediate rejection from a major journal. The (volunteered, tough, unpaid, often unrecognized) job of the referee is to assess the scientific quality of the paper. It shouldn't be the job of the referee to waddle over stuff that is obscured by very poor writing.

@MartinArgerami, i don't agree with you at all. Content should matter mainly, exposition could be developed at any point if revision is given with a strict note. If the authors still don't take it seriously, then ofcourse a rejection.

@MartinArgerami Poorly written manuscripts should not be published in any journal, irrespective of how major. That doesn't mean all such papers should be rejected out of hand. If a paper is sufficiently poorly written that I can't tell if its any good I return it to the editor and say "I can't tell if this should be published as the lanuage is so bad I can't judge it". If the editor wants to reject it on that basis, thats the editors decision, but personally if I were the editor I'd return it to the authors and say "resubmit when the lanuage is better".

In the end its the science that matters. Lanuage can always be improved. But that doesn't mean its the reviewers job to improve it, just to point out it needs improving.

@IanSudbery: when I referee, from time to time I'm asked what I think of a paper (usually when an editor is trying to decide whether the paper is worth refereeing). But most of the time I'm asked whether to accept or reject. The final decision is in the editor's hand (or the editorial board, sometimes) but referees are certainly asked to accept or reject.

"meticulusly catelogued all the typos" - I see that.

I assume the context (vaguely implied by your question) of mathematics journals.

Occasionally, I review a paper that is submitted to a high-quality journal that is one of the journals regarded as the most prestigious journals in my field, and the manuscript is sloppy

A high quality journal needs to publish high quality content. Sloppiness of the level you describe does not sound acceptable for the standards set by top journals. I certainly would not recommend publication in such circumstances until the quality of the paper has been brought up to match or exceed the standards the journal and its readers are expecting. A few typos or ungrammatical sentences here and there are okay; major inaccuracies and notational inconsistencies, especially ones that make the mathematical content hard or impossible to understand, are not. The identity of the authors, whether it’s written by a PhD student etc, are immaterial.
That being said, if the math is solid and of sufficient quality for the journal, I wouldn’t outright recommend rejecting the paper, since issues related to presentation can be corrected (whereas the content being not novel or exciting or important enough is not typically a correctable issue). I would simply say — and have said in the past, when I had similar concerns myself - that the paper needs a major revision, point out at least some of the issues, and say I look forward to re-evaluating the work once those issues have been addressed.
If the authors then resubmit a revised paper and the revised paper is still not up to standards, the only fair response is to recommend rejection. Not every work, even not every really good work, deserves to be published in a top journal.
As for your other questions:

As a reviewer, should I take the sloppiness in a manuscript as a warning for potential sloppiness in the research?

No. But are you talking about mathematics here? If you are reviewing a math paper you would check it for correctness yourself, right? You should not be performing your evaluation based on heuristic indicators such as the prevalence of typos. Perhaps one can say that sloppiness can be a good reason for a bit of extra vigilance when evaluating the paper for correctness. But then again, as I have said above, the sloppiness would already be sufficient reason to send the paper back to the authors and ask them to fix the issues, so I would simply hold back on evaluating correctness until they submit their revised version.

Would it be fair to reject a paper on the ground of a sloppy manuscript?

See above.

Would it be fair to recommend that the authors go to a lower-tier journal? — this is not ideal anyway, since, in the end, I would like all published research to be rigorously checked, regardless of the tier of the journal.

You don’t have to explicitly make such a recommendation, but it’s quite reasonable to make it. As for it being not ideal, I suggest focusing on the task at hand, which is to review the paper for this journal. If you point out the issues and the authors ignore them and resubmit to a lower tier journal, that would be up to that journal to think what to do about the problem.

Would it be fair to mention my worry in the special note to the Editor?

Sure, but personally I never use the “confidential” editor’s note option and don’t see what it’s for other than for use by very squeamish or conflict-averse reviewers. If you have a valid concern then you would be doing the authors a favor by sharing it with them, not just with the editor.
On the other hand, as I said above, the concerns that “sloppiness in writing implies sloppiness in research” or “hmm, this paper smells like it’s written by a PhD student; where’s the senior scientist?” do not strike me as particularly valid concerns. It’s fine to use the Editor’s note, but you should point out actual issues, not inferences based on shaky statistical logic.

My two cents:
Depending on where the authors are originating, typos and language errors I find very annoying, but do understand that not everyone is a native speaker or has excellent English skills. So what I always do is remark that the level of language is not up to par and need thorough revisiting, but I would not hold that against the authors. I recently wrote a paper with a quite senior (in experience and position) colleague whose passages for a joint paper were so bad in terms of spelling and grammar that I had to rewrite almost everything.
Concerning the other issues: those probably often do stem from inexperienced writers, but I would not necessarily assume that it means that the research was conducted by these inexperienced researchers without supervision and might thus be flawed. Rather, after a project is finished, the task of writing everything up will often fall to the inexperienced, more junior members of the project. And the supervisors might wave the paper through without proper revision because they are too busy (not an excuse, they really should!). So a sloppy manuscript might not necessarily mean sloppy research, but rather sloppy and unsupervised writing.
When encountering a sloppy manuscript, I always write a note to the editor about it, because they are the person in charge with making a decision.

I agree with the first part and this is why I didn't list grammatical or language errors in my question. Typos are a different thing, say someone wanted to write "Newton" but wrote "Nweton". If the paper is full of those, it really starts to look like a rushed work, and is difficult to justify just on the grounds of the authors not being native speakers.

The second part would still worry me. If the senior researchers were busy at the time of submission, why didn't the authors wait with the submission until such time when the manuscript can be thoroughly checked. And if the senior researchers are always busy and never able to check student's work, then we're back to my original worry: how can I trust that they had the time to check the student's research while it was being conducted?

There are some good answers, but let me add one more point/option: You, as a referee, are not obliged to review. It is perfectly acceptable to contact the editor and write: "I am willing to review this manuscript, but I kindly ask that the authors fix issue xyz first."

Thank you, I didn't know this was an option! I wonder what happens next, do you know what actions the Editor takes in that case? And what happens if another reviewer has already began their review of the paper as it is?

That seems like something the editor would have to handle and I cannot report first hand experience with that, though I do remember that something like this happened to me as an author in an early career stage. In any case, the earlier you make your concerns known, the easier it is for the editor to act appropriately.
