Reviewing a paper that's badly written such that reading it takes a long time
I'm reviewing a paper for a journal, with a mathematical nature. Its content, from what I can gather from an initial pass, is probably ok. However, it has a tendency to reinvent things with its own idiosyncratic terminology and notation and expresses things in a generally awkward way, such that understanding it in full detail is taking me a long time.
I already asked for an extension from the journal and don't really want to drag it out any longer, for my own sake as well as theirs, as I have other things I need to do. But at the same time it doesn't seem fair to recommend rejection purely on the basis that I personally struggled to read it. I think it is objectively awkwardly written and I don't think my difficulty reading it has to do with a lack of expertise on my part, but that doesn't mean someone else wouldn't find it much easier to follow than I do.
So it seems like my only option is to submit a review admitting that I didn't understand it all and explaining the reason why, without being able to comment on all of its main contributions. Of course I can give suggestions for how to reformulate the parts I did understand, and general pointers to the literature that might help with the rest.
My question is whether this is considered a reasonable thing to do in this situation, or whether there might be another option that I haven't considered. I generally feel that a review should check the correctness of a paper's mathematical content, and I feel like I'm letting the authors down by not being able to do that.

Related ;) https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/214102/are-there-any-special-actions-that-i-should-execute-as-a-reviewer-of-a-sloppy-ma

Part of being a good researcher is communicating thoughts well. If the paper isn't well written at all, I would recommend rejection citing the poor writing and lack of clarity, possibly leaving the door open for a resubmit.

"I generally feel that a review should check the correctness of a paper's mathematical content, and I feel like I'm letting the authors down by not being able to do that." No, it's the other way around: it's the authors who are letting the referees down by not putting enough effort into making their writing clear.

My most unpleasant refereeing experience would have been made much easier by saying "I can't read this paper because of this terrible notation and messed up definition. I'll take another look once they've been fixed." rather than slogging through

Reinventing notation means that I have to do 1+3+5+1 times the job. 1 time for the review, 3 times to learn a new notation, 5 to connect it to the rest I know and 1 to read it again and understand it now.

There's a lot of negativity about poorly written papers on this page, but the thing is these things are quite subjective. What I meant to say in the question was that the awkwardness made it very difficult for me to read, but that I felt someone else might find it a lot easier. The review would have been easier if I'd felt that nobody else would be able to read it either.

@N.Virgo I am pretty sure that "a tendency to reinvent things with its own idiosyncratic terminology" is universally considered an obstacle to easy comprehension, rather than being some personal idiosyncrasy of yours.

@AdamPřenosil It really matters if the idiosyncratic notation is essential or a quirk.

Yes, what you suggest seems reasonable (and proper). You aren't expected to expend extreme or superhuman efforts on the paper. Suggest major revisions are necessary before the paper would be readable by the typical reader of the journal.
Don't neglect to mention non-standard terminology and/or notation.
I'm wondering if the paper was written by someone relatively unschooled who needs to re-do what is already known. Not a crank, but someone who needs more background.
What you suggest seems useful to both editor and author.

This. The journal probably should not publish something that is correct but unreadable. So pointing out that it is unreadable is a worthwhile review.

Adam already came close to my point, but I believe this is worth an answer by itself.

I generally feel that a review should check the correctness of a paper's mathematical content

This is wrong, as in "not enough". Reviewers should comment on whether a paper contributes to advancing the discipline. The correctness of a paper's mathematical content is one dimension in which a paper can advance the discipline, or fail to contribute. But there are other dimensions, which are absolutely equally important:

An adequate engagement with prior art and the current state of the literature. No matter how much you contribute, if you do not engage with what other people are doing right now, then your contribution falls short. People reading the paper should be able to understand the context. Major revision.
Missing information. In math, there is a fine line between giving proofs in detail and leaving details to readers (who are presumably knowledgeable in the field), but "I have a wonderful proof for this proposition; unfortunately page constraints mean that I cannot give it" was fine for Fermat but not for us lesser mortals. In other disciplines, failure to give important information about experimental setup or study participants can sink the best (alleged) contributions. Major revision or reject.
Inappropriate methods. Less of an issue in math, more so in other fields. I am a statistician working in forecasting, and I will recommend rejection if a submission clearly shows data leakage. Reject.
And yes: clarity of exposition. No matter what you did, if your intended audience cannot understand it, then you did not contribute to the scientific conversation. And it is incumbent on the author to make sure they are understandable. Sure, a reviewer can help, and should do so if they think the underlying scientific contribution is worth investing the time and effort. But the work and the responsibility falls on the authors. Reject and resubmit, or reject outright.


Of course. I didn't mean a review should only check the mathematical correctness, and I don't think my text really implied that. But I do feel it's a particularly important aspect of a review, because it's one of the most helpful things a reviewer can do for the authors rather than the journal.

I would say it's kind of hard to say whether any given review comment benefits "the journal" more than "the authors" or "the readers". My motivation as an author is to further the scientific conversation, and the entire review process is designed to help me achieve that goal. So an improvement in any of the dimensions I discuss above (or, conversely, gatekeeping to keep bad manuscripts out) arguably benefits everyone involved.

I don't disagree, but speaking for myself as an author, the main benefit I look for when submitting a mathematical paper to a journal rather than just arXiv is that an experienced person will go through the maths carefully and give their comments. Sure, there's also the stuff about publishing being good for your career etc., but that's just politics and I only care about it to the extent that I'm forced to.

Note that I did not say anything about your citation count or your career. "Furthering the scientific conversation" is quite a different thing. (I work in industry; few people around me - including my manager - have any idea about how publishing works or about citation indices. I publish because I believe it makes the world a better place.)

Perhaps you're lucky in that respect. I write because it makes the world a better place, but I publish because I have to.

It sounds to me as if you already spend much more time on the article than you should have. Basically, once it becomes clear the article would need significant improvements in presentation, it is fair to ask that this is done before you keep reading it.
Something like the following makes for a useful referee report:

There is probably some merit in the mathematical content of this
submission. However its presentation makes it so inaccessible that a major
rewrite seems necessary to even adequately judge the relevance and
correctness of the mathematical claims.
A (highly non-exhaustive) list of examples follows:

The authors invented their own terminology for skrimpy widgets, instead of following the standard..


It is then up to the editor to decide whether they want to give the authors the chance to revise or not, and subsequently, up to the authors to decide whether to try that rewrite or not.

Yes. If they're that bad, these are typically my fastest reviews. I'm definitely not going to spend more time reading the paper than it seems like they did writing it. (Although my fastest review might have been one where what I wrote was something along the lines of, "This paper seems like a fine paper, but its topic has nothing to do with the topics of this conference." It really was a fine paper -- for some other conference. NB: I didn't check to see if the paper was plagiarized or anything, though.)

One way to phrase this is that the purpose of a referee is to give advice to the author that helps them to improve the paper, and then, when there is no advice left to give, evaluate the paper. It's not necessary to evaluate the paper until the final publication decision is made which is after the advice has been given.


However, it has a tendency to reinvent things with its own idiosyncratic terminology and notation and expresses things in a generally awkward way, such that understanding it in full detail is taking me a long time.

I'd mark it for major review and clearly state that the terminology is "misleading" - highligt [colour one] the 'own idiosyncratic terminology' - and nontation as well - higlight [colour two] where it 'expresses things in a generally awkward way'.
You can clearly state, that you stopped reviewing the manuscript before reaching the end because of the language. It is understandable and this feedback can open discussion how to improve the paper.

You got a very good advice in the three other answers. And yet, it might happen (although, the probability that it will happen to you or to any particular mathematician, is pretty low) that you should ignore all this advice and accept the paper even though it is barely readable. Recognizing that you are dealing with such a paper is not easy and there is no rule of thumb for doing this. Instead of trying to achieve the impossible, I will give just two examples (I could  give more, but I will not). There is a mathematician, Mikhail Gromov, one of the best mathematicians alive (if the name is unfamiliar, just google him). In 1985 and 1987 Gromov published two papers:
Mikhail Gromov, "Pseudo holomorphic curves in symplectic manifolds." Inventiones Mathematicae vol. 82, 1985, pp. 307-347.
Mikhail Gromov, "Hyperbolic Groups". In: Gersten, Steve M. (ed.). Essays in Group Theory. Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications. Vol. 8. New York: Springer. pp. 75–263. (1987)
To say that these papers are very hard to read would be an understatement. If one were to apply the criteria mentioned in the three other answers, both papers should have been rejected. And yet, mathematics is better off that these papers were published, pretty much "as is." These papers changed two fields of mathematics (arguably, created two fields of mathematics): symplectic topology and geometric group theory. Here is how Donaldson characterizes (correctly) the first paper:

The terminology pseudoholomorphic curve (or J-holomorphic curve) was introduced by Gromov in 1986 [sic]. The notion has transformed the field of symplectic topology and has a bearing on many other
areas such as algebraic geometry, string theory, and
4-manifold theory...

Both papers introduce a variety of definitions and state a number of theorems (typically, with barely any proofs). It took mathematical community about 15 years to get a clean and complete treatment of these. I do not know who and how refereed the first paper, but I have some knowledge of how the refereeing process of the second paper took place. The first referee wrote several pages of comments of the form "prove or give a reference." The second referee ignored all of these and accepted the paper. It takes mathematical maturity and vision on the part of the referee to do so. As I said, we are all better off as the result.

One shouldn't let perfect be the enemy of good, of course, but are you sure Gromov being asked to revise these papers would have been such a terrible outcome? Would he have refused to publish altogether in that case? If not, is it that you consider a few months of work by him to be worth more than many years of work by the community?

@Anyon: Gromov's reaction in the case I know was along the lines of "please, find another referee." And he probably would have published elsewhere.

I’m not sure "if you are famous enough you can just force people into publishing your work anyway" is the state science should strive for.

@MisterMiyagi: The misunderstanding expressed in your comment is exactly why I wrote my answer. Maybe one day you will understand the difference...

@MoisheKohan I am well aware what you are trying to say. I just disagree with it. Maybe one day you will understand the difference…

"Hard to read" and "reinvent things with idiosyratic terminology" are two different features of a paper. "Hard to read" paper may still be a high-quality work on difficult topic and making it easier may bloat the text significantly. On the other hand "idiosyncratic terminology" just messes things up and cleaning up may shorten the paper without losing any (novel) ideas.

@Crowley: That's quite true.

@MoisheKohan The mathematical community may collectively be better off. On the other hand, I have a vivid memory that almost 20 years ago, as someone doing a PhD in a completely different area, I was very frustrated that a result I needed was always cited as being in the hyperbolic paper, yet I was unable to find an explanation that I could follow. In the end my office-mate referred me to the notes of Alonso et al which did stoop to giving an actual proof

@YemonChoi: Of course. You just had to ask right people for better references (they also would have directed you to the books by Ghys et al, by Delzant et al, Bridson and Haefliger, etc). If you think about history of science in general, this is actually a rule: a breakthrough, followed by an extensive (and sometimes very long) clean-up stage. As the result, nobody reads original papers of Newton, Leibnitz, Poincare, Einstein, etc, except for science historians. But without those original papers, science would be nowhere close to where we are.

@YemonChoi: Of course, Gromov in principle could have provided detailed proofs. He did not for a good reason (which is not because he regarded this beneath him): It would have required a text about 5 times linger than his and significantly delayed publication and, hence, development of the field.

@MoisheKohan: I agree that it is better for mathematics that Gromov's papers were published, and given that he was unwilling to write out complete proofs (and in many cases, even complete definitions!) accepting them as-is seems like the right thing to do. However, I strongly disagree with you that he had a "good reason". Gromov is a great mathematician, but plenty of equally great mathematicians (Borel, Deligne, Serre, etc) could have used their stature to avoid the hard work of writing their papers but did not. We should not celebrate the fact that Gromov is less responsible than them.

(sorry for commenting on a 2-month old thread, but if I had self-control I'd be doing something other than playing on the internet...)
